# Any ideas why my phone is not connecting to my Icom ID-51E PLUS2?

Tags: icom, icom-id-51-plus2

I have the cable connected from my phone, a Samsung Galaxy S6, to my brand new Icom ID-51E PLUS2 and when I run the app I get this error:

[image]

I think I correctly set up my radio for this, as you can see in this video:

https://youtu.be/m1llAnDgYcg

Any ideas what else could be a problem?

Comment: I can't give you an answer but I recommend the eham.net forums (consider the Elmer's forum) for these kind of questions.  Often very good response rate for these kind of questions on specific rigs.

Comment: Thank you @K7PEH. I just signed up for those forums now I'll wait for my account to be approved.

Answer (score 2):

As your Icom is 'brand new' as you described it, I would strongly recommend to contact Icom [support](http://www.icomamerica.com/en/support/default.aspx)

> Technical Support Department
>
> Dedicated number  800-253-1498
>
> Monday - Friday 4AM to 5PM PST

They are there to help you.

Just in case you are wondering: I did not find a number for Icom support in Argentina (based on your call) nor did I find a satisfying answer from [Icom UK website](http://icomuk.co.uk/Icom_Support) (based on the fact that your user profile lists UK as your location).

However you may just want to [contact](http://icomuk.co.uk/Contact_Us) Icom UK, to see if they have a support department locally to you.

Failing all that, you can try to contact the Japanese headquarters [support](http://www.icom.co.jp/world/support/contact/)